# Tomcat6 - SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: linux, ssl, https, tomcat

After following the instructions to setup a secure http connection on my tomcat server (link: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html), I had this error pop up when I requested https://x.x.x.x:8443 :

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to 192.168.1.45:8443. SSL received a record that  exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Does that mean that the ssl file is corrupted or what?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the missing part of the error?

Comment: @Xavierjazz what do you mean by missing?

Comment: It looks to me as if the right side is cut off. The first line ends at "that" and the 2nd ends with the word "receive". I can read the entire 3rd line.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I don't see a missing part. Maybe you can see the error better if you go to `https://thesalmonkiller.com:8443/`